# How to contain text in bootstrap 4 card with horizontal scroll card flip component

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a horizontal scroll allowing for the cards to flip. The problem that i'm having is figuring out how to contain the text to the card. With the property 'white-space: nowrap;' on the .scrollcards class it makes the text go outside of the cards. However, this is also what is allowing the cards to scroll. My question is how to contain the text by wrapping all text in the card while keeping all of the other current properties working as they are now. https://codepen.io/zepzia/pen/opyxKy

```
<section>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

  <div class="scrollcards">

            <!-- Card Flip -->
            <div class="card-flip card-main">
                <div class="flip">
                    <div class="front">
                        <!-- front content -->
                        <div class="card">
                          <img class="card-img-top" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="100%x180" style="height: 180px; width: 100%; display: block;" data-holder-rendered="true">
                          <div class="card-block">
                            <h4 class="card-title">Card Flip</h4>
                            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>

                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                        <!-- back content -->
                        <div class="card">
                          <div class="card-block">
                            <h4 class="card-title">Card Flip</h4>
                            <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">Support card subtitle</h6>
                          </div>
                          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Image [100%x180]" data-holder-rendered="true" style="height: 180px; width: 100%; display: block;">
                          <div class="card-block">
                            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>

                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Card Flip -->



            <!-- Card Flip -->
            <div class="card-flip-one card-main">
                <div class="flip-one">
                    <div class="front">
                        <!-- front content -->
                        <div class="card">
                          <img class="card-img-top" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="100%x180" style="height: 180px; width: 100%; display: block;" data-holder-rendered="true">
                          <div class="card-block">
                            <h4 class="card-title">Card Flip</h4>
                            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>

                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                        <!-- back content -->
                        <div class="card">
                          <div class="card-block">
                            <h4 class="card-title">Card Flip</h4>
                            <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">Support card subtitle</h6>
                          </div>
                          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Image [100%x180]" data-holder-rendered="true" style="height: 180px; width: 100%; display: block;">
                          <div class="card-block">
                            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>

                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Card Flip -->




            <!-- Card Flip -->
            <div class="card-flip-two card-main">
                <div class="flip-two">
                    <div class="front">
                        <!-- front content -->
                        <div class="card">
                          <img class="card-img-top" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="100%x180" style="height: 180px; width: 100%; display: block;" data-holder-rendered="true">
                          <div class="card-block">
                            <h4 class="card-title">Card Flip</h4>
                            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>

                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                        <!-- back content -->
                        <div class="card">
                          <div class="card-block">
                            <h4 class="card-title">Card Flip</h4>
                            <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">Support card subtitle</h6>
                          </div>
                          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Image [100%x180]" data-holder-rendered="true" style="height: 180px; width: 100%; display: block;">
                          <div class="card-block">
                            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>

                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Card Flip -->



            <!-- Card Flip -->
            <div class="card-flip-three card-main">
                <div class="flip-three">
                    <div class="front">
                        <!-- front content -->
                        <div class="card">
                          <img class="card-img-top" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="100%x180" style="height: 180px; width: 100%; display: block;" data-holder-rendered="true">
                          <div class="card-block">
                            <h4 class="card-title">Card Flip</h4>
                            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>

                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                        <!-- back content -->
                        <div class="card">
                          <div class="card-block">
                            <h4 class="card-title">Card Flip</h4>
                            <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">Support card subtitle</h6>
                          </div>
                          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Image [100%x180]" data-holder-rendered="true" style="height: 180px; width: 100%; display: block;">
                          <div class="card-block">
                            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>

                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Card Flip -->



            <!-- Card Flip -->
            <div class="card-flip-four card-main">
                <div class="flip-four">
                    <div class="front">
                        <!-- front content -->
                        <div class="card">
                          <img class="card-img-top" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="100%x180" style="height: 180px; width: 100%; display: block;" data-holder-rendered="true">
                          <div class="card-block">
                            <h4 class="card-title">Card Flip</h4>
                            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>

                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                        <!-- back content -->
                        <div class="card">
                          <div class="card-block">
                            <h4 class="card-title">Card Flip</h4>
                            <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">Support card subtitle</h6>
                          </div>
                          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Image [100%x180]" data-holder-rendered="true" style="height: 180px; width: 100%; display: block;">
                          <div class="card-block">
                            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>

                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Card Flip -->

  </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

```
   .scrollcards {
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 550px;
}

div.scrollcards .card-main {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: auto; 
    width: 350px;
}

.card-main .card {
  height: 400px;
  width: 350px;
  white-space: hidden;
}


.card-flip,
.card-flip-one,
.card-flip-two,
.card-flip-three,
.card-flip-four {
  perspective: 1000px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

 .flip,
 .flip,
.flip-one,
.flip-one,
.flip-two,
.flip-two,
.flip-three,
.flip-three,
.flip-four,
.flip-four{
   perspective: 1000px;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card-flip,
.card-flip-one,
.card-flip-two,
.card-flip-three,
.card-flip-four,
.front,
.back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 480px;
}

.flip,
.flip-one,
.flip-two,
.flip-three,
.flip-four {
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}

.front,
.back {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.front {
  z-index: 2;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}





 var cardFlip = document.querySelector(".card-flip");

cardFlip.addEventListener("click", function(){
  cardFlip.classList.toggle("flip");
});

var cardFlipOne = document.querySelector(".card-flip-one");

cardFlipOne.addEventListener("click", function(){
  cardFlipOne.classList.toggle("flip-one");
});

var cardFlipTwo = document.querySelector(".card-flip-two");

cardFlipTwo.addEventListener("click", function(){
  cardFlipTwo.classList.toggle("flip-two");
});

var cardFlipThree = document.querySelector(".card-flip-three");

cardFlipThree.addEventListener("click", function(){
  cardFlipThree.classList.toggle("flip-three");
});

var cardFlipFour = document.querySelector(".card-flip-four");

cardFlipFour.addEventListener("click", function(){
  cardFlipFour.classList.toggle("flip-four");
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i'm not sure how you want the text to be exactly, but if you add this css to your `.card-text` it will clip your text (keep it contained) and add ellipsis (three dots...) at the end of your text.

CSS:

```
.card-text {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here's a jsFiddle showing the result: https://jsfiddle.net/0184zgjL/

if you want the text to be scrollable, the css will be like this:

```
.card-text {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

and there will be a scrollbar allowing you to see all the text.

Here's a jsFiddle with this behavior: https://jsfiddle.net/0184zgjL/1/

FINAL EDIT

if you just change the css in the `.card-text` to be `white-space: normal` it works..

```
.card-text {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

here's another jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0184zgjL/2/

Comment: I am trying to get any text in the card to wrap

Comment: @Tripp updated my answer under the final edit section. from my understanding you can't change the CSS on the `scrollcards` so i didn't, i just added 1 line of css on `.card-text`